# How to seperate HH, MM, SS, and merdian from this string in c++ "XY:56:21AM" ? Following program getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Input string "XY:56:21AM". I am trying to convert this string to HH,MM,SS & meridian.
I tried substr but not getting desired output. Below code getting segmentation fault.

```
string Conversion(string str) {

    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ':'), str.end());

    string tmp = "";
    std::vector<string> data;

   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
   {
      if(i < 2){
        tmp.push_back(str[i]);
      }
      if(i < 4 && i > 1){
          if(i == 2){
            tmp.push_back('\0');
            data.push_back(tmp);
            tmp = "";
          }
          tmp.push_back(str[i]);
      }
   }
   tmp.push_back('\0');
            data.push_back(tmp);
            tmp = "";
   for(auto i=data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything when you said you're returning a string, but at first glance I can't see anything else very wrong (anything else that could cause a segmentation fault anyway).

Comment: You don't need to add extra `\0` in string, `tmp.push_back('\0')` can safely be removed.

Answer (score 5):

If each field has fixed size of 2 chars, why not to use 4 `substr`s?

```
std::string str = "12:34:56AM";
std::vector<std::string> parts;

parts.push_back(str.substr(0, 2));
parts.push_back(str.substr(3, 2));
parts.push_back(str.substr(6, 2));
parts.push_back(str.substr(8, 2));
```

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions:

```
std::smatch match;
std::regex_match(str, match, std::regex(R"((\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)(AM|PM))"));
for (std::size_t i = 1; i < match.size(); ++i)
    parts.push_back(match[i].str());
```